# String.split to stop at last element python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using str.split to split the data I have after a regex from one column into two columns.

The data is:

```
DATA_SET 
1  98
2 176
3 277 
.... 
16 790

DATA_SET
1   8
2  37
3 378
.... 
16 899
```

I have a piece of code that works with individual data sets to split the column into two columns.

`f = pd.read_table('my_file.txt')`

`f[['D1 ', 'D2']] = f['DATA_SET'].str.split(expand=True)`

How can I specify to the code that when it reaches the item “16” it needs to stop the split operation? And do it again after it encounters the next “DATA_SET”

Answer (score 0):

Apply the split to the rows you are interested, i.e where index is less equal 16

```
f[['D1 ', 'D2']] = f.loc[:16, 'DATA_SET'].\
    str.split(expand=True)
```

Comment: Specifying the line number worked. But how do I make it do the same action on the next DATA_SET and give out another set of 2 columns with the individual data?

Comment: I don't really understand what you need, can you edit the question with this info and also post the expected output?That way I can find a different approach.